# visual studio 2013 - string must be exactly one character long

Tags: string, visual-studio-2013, converters

Visual Studio is giving me the following error when I submit and store in the database.

"string must be exactly one character long"

to try to resolve tried this but without success:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@nomeEmpresa", OleDb.OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToChar(cbxEmpresa.Text)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@nomeContacto", OleDb.OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToChar(txtNomeContacto.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@apelidoContacto", OleDb.OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToChar(txtApelidoContacto.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@funcao", OleDb.OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToChar(txtFuncao.Text)
```

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: why are you converting everything to a Char? be sure that you have values in those textboxes and comboboxes. Convert it to the CORRECT data type.

Comment: Can you explain why your parameters are all to type Integer and you try to pass a char as their values

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the documentation of [Convert.ToChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5f3ew98y(v=vs.110).aspx) you could read

> Converts the first character of a specified string to a Unicode
> character. Namespace:  System Assembly:  mscorlib (in mscorlib.dll)
>
> Syntax
> public static char ToChar(    string value )
>
> valueType: System.String
>
> A string of length 1.

That's the reason of your error.

However your code seems to be incorrect. If you want to pass Integer values types by your user to your sql you need to convert your input using something like `Int32.TryParse(textbox.text)`

Instead if you want to pass string values you need to change your parameter type to SqlDbType.NVarChar.

Answer (score 0):

Convert.ToChar(string) requires that the string only contain a single character.  You need to gaurrantee this for each of the strings before you call it, or manually select the first character from the string, or something similar.

Docs for Convert.ToChar(string), throws FormatException "The length of value is not 1."
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5f3ew98y(v=vs.110).aspx